# Research Topics Needed

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, open-problem

This coming academic year a professor has asked me to find some topics that I wish to pursue to write about. The problem/topic that will be discussed doesn't have to be open, but my trouble is that I need ideas for topics in the first place.

Can anyone suggest research topics dealing with preferably Combinatorics? It is my favorite subject so far since I haven't delved into Graph Theory too much.

Comment: Douglas West and Dan Archdeacon both maintain lists of open problems on their websites, which I will link to below. I would say nearly any of the problems could be understood by a motivated undergrad. Most of these are graph theory problems, but there are several purely combinatorial problems there too. http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~west/openp/ http://www.emba.uvm.edu/~darchdea/problems/problems.html

Comment: Very nice resource. Thank you

Comment: http://www.usna.edu/Users/math/tsm/Research/Book_HowToGuardAnArtGallery_Michael/Sample_Chapter_Art_Gallery_Michael.pdf